# Prevent opening new window or new tab on the same site?

Tags: php

I want to prevent users from opening multiple tabs or windows open to my site. Each page has a different audio file that should not be playing at the same time. It also screws up a popup with background music. I also want any solution to work across various browser types.

I've tried javascript cookies, but they don't seem to work across multiple instances of the same page open in different tabs or windows. If they did work I would simply close down the new window if that cookies was set. (Actually, I think that solution works in safari, but nothing else.) Do php session variable work across multiple instances of the same page?

I don't care if a solution does not work across in incognito mode or across different browser types on the same page simultaneously. That's just asking for trouble.

Comment: You cannot simply close a window on the client side. You can prevent one from opening on certain conditions, that's all. And for very good reasons. Cookies certainly do "work accross windows and tabs", as long as those are instances of the same browser. And obviously php sessions do, since the server does not know about windows and tabs, as long as the sessions are not identified via a url query parameter.

Comment: This does not sound like a good idea to me. Really. You want your site to take over the control of the client's browser and decide which URLs are allowed and which are not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if there is an active tab playing music using the PageVisibility API, then other tabs don't play music!

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pagevisibility/intro/

Comment: This answer was a bit bare-bones, so I added at least a link and the name of the API.